# Extract Json Data and display it in HTML forms

Tags: php, html, json

```
{"hari.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},"hari.net":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"dotnet"}}
```

We need to run the loop using php and display it in the below format
Like we need to display in the TR and TD's tags in the HTMl form using PHP, JSON and HTML form

Like:

```
Hari.com    regthroughothers    price  
Hari.net    regthroughothers    price
```

Can Anyone please display in the Table and also i need the status to be print in separate TD and price on separate TD.Please help me like the above example
Based on the TLD's i want to display the Output.

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is confusing: the title says "form", but the question refers to table elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
 $json1='{"hari.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},"hari.net":      {"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"dotnet"}}';

$json1 = json_decode($json1);

 foreach($json1 as $key=>$sel_rows)     
  {
      echo $key . " " . " welcome " . " price"; 
       echo " status: ". $sel_rows->status;
      echo "\n";                                             
  }
?>
```

Comment: can you please display it in the HTMl FORM

Comment: Once you parse the JSON with `json_decode`, just use ordinary associative array access to access any parts of it, e.g. `$json1['hari.com']['status']` will return the status.

Comment: Please , refere again updated code : Using $sel_rows->status;

Comment: How can i display the Output like Godaddy [link] (http://www.godaddy.com/domains/searchresults.aspx?ci=54814), Can you please help me with the code for the Tlds

Comment: i am getting exatly ur queation, can you descrip more in details, so i can help better.

Comment: like godaddy when we search for a domain, the out put is displayed according to the TLD's like.com, .net etc, so similarly i want to display the out put in the same format with the base of the TLD's, can you please help me with the code